# Only allow sku to be added if other product exists in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, addtocart

I have a sku, let's call it sku100 for now. I only want that sku to be allowed to be added to cart if any other sku exists in the cart. I tried looking at shopping cart price rules but can't find any combinations to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()` method and set validation like this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0));
$skus = array('sku100');
$sku = $product->getSku();
if(count($cart->getAllItems()))
{
    if(in_array($sku,$skus)){
        $msg = "Product add to cart";
    }
    else{
        $msg = "Please select another product";
            throw new Exception($msg);
    }
}
```

you can also use product add to cart event set validation same as above

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a new product attribute to store the required SKUs *(i.e. `required_sku`)* and add an observer to `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

config.xml

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <some_alias>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>my_module/observer</class>
            <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
        </some_alias>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

Observer.php

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote      = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $product    = $observer->getProduct();
    $cartItems  = $quote->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    # new product attribute 'required_sku'
    $required   = $product->getRequiredSku();
    $canBeAdded = false;

    if ($required) {
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            if ($required == $item->getProduct()->getSku()) {
                $canBeAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$canBeAdded) {
            $quote->getQuote()->removeItem($quote->getId());
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product ' . $required . ' has to be added first.')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Full code here: [How to exclude products being added to cart based on products attributes?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178365/how-to-exclude-products-being-added-to-cart-based-on-products-attributes/178996#178996)</sup>