# How can I add custom product link in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Let's suppose I want to add a custom link to my product in M1, is there a way to do that? These products would be linked to an external site. I have two buttons on my website - Buy Now And Add to Cart. Buy now redirects customers directly to the checkout page.

I want this feature to function something like this:

If there is no custom URL entered in the backend, Magento should create product URL as it usually does and *both buy now & add to cart button should appear.*

If there is a custom product URL entered, Magento should use that link. **ONLY** 'buy now' button should appear in that case, and if customers click on buy now button, it should redirect them to the external website.

Here's the code in addtocart.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $buyNowTitle = $this->__('Buy Now'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart  actions-wrapper">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-top: 5px;">
        <a  title="<?php echo $buyNowTitle ?>" id="product-buynow-button" class="button btn-cart product-add-btn" onclick="productBuyNowForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buyNowTitle ?></span></span></a> 
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart product-add-btn" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: could you share how you added `Buy Now ` button and in which phtml ?

Comment: @Pawan I have added the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround : you can have `product's attribute` for storing custom buying url and check if it exist for the product you can remove the link in phtml file.

You need to set **Manage Stock** `false` for those type of product.

And also you can prevent these type of product to be added in cart by following refrences

[Preventing a product from being added to cart in magento](https://webkul.com/blog/preventing-product-from-being-added-to-cart/)

[How to exclude products being added to cart based on products attributes?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178365/how-to-exclude-products-being-added-to-cart-based-on-products-attributes)